# How to group active users of transactions in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections - `users` and `transactions` in my MongoDB.

```
transactions:
created - date
created_by - user ID

users:
ID
```

I'm trying to determine per month, the users that have actively transacted within the last 90 days of the month. For example:

```
Date - mmm-yyyy Active users
Jan 2020    10
Feb 2020    15
March 2020  33
```

Is that possible?

I'm fairly new to MongoDB's aggregations and I'm not even sure how to approach this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you provide examples of your data, and the expected output?

Comment: _"... actively transacted within the last 90 days of the month. Is that possible?"_ I guess you mean just last 90 days. You can take a look at the `$lookup` aggregation ("join") stage which allows querying on two collections. You can specify multiple conditions using the `pipeline` option of the `$lookup`.

Comment: @MohammedYousry Hi there, i've updated the thread.

Comment: Did you record your users' lastLogin/ all login time?